# Is it possible to add 2 dimensional Lists in c#?

Tags: c#, list, collections

I am having a list of Properties. I want to add these PropertiesCollections for multiple elements in the same page. That is something like

```
[0] => List
       ([0] => ID
        [1] => Name
        [2] => Add
        [3] => PhoneNo
        [4] => City)
[1] => List
    (And so on....


internal class PropertiesCollection : List<Properties>
{
}

internal class Properties
{
}

PropertiesCollection collection = new PropertiesCollection ();
```

How can i achieve

```
Something[0,collection[0]]  
Something[0,collection[1]]
Something[1,collection[0]]
Something[1,collection[1]] ?
```

Comment: Like a multi-dimensional array?

Comment: Can you not use List of PropertiesCollection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can do a list of lists

```
List<List<string>> list=new List<List<string>>();
```

Then to access individual elements you could do something like this:

```
List<string> list=listlist[0];
        int i=list[0];
```

Or use a foreach loop etc.

Comment: How can I get it based on Index?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a 'List to do what you want

```
private enum Property { ID = 0, Name, Add, PhoneNo, City };
string[] details = new string[5] { "1", "Frank Butcher". "Y", 
                                   "02087891256", "London (Albert Square)" };
List<string[]> propertyList = new List<string[]>();
propertyList.Add(details);
```

Getting Frank Butchers name would then be done like

```
string franksName = propertyList[0][(int)Property.Name];
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This may be old however after two days of headbanging and looking at so many articles regarding arrays, lists and multi-dimensions your example was perfect for my needs

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
List<PropertiesCollection> propColl = new List<PropertiesCollection>();
PropertiesCollection coll = new PropertiesCollection();
coll.Add(new Properties(some parameters));
coll.Add(new Properties(some parameters));
propColl.Add(coll);
propColl[0][0];
```